# Photoshop perspective transform grayed out for embedded illustrator file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I keep coming across this problem randomly in my documents.

I’d like to *Free Transform → Perspective Transform,* but the option is grayed out.

If I hit <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then drag one of the handles while holding <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>, I’m not able to move each handle independently (Perspective Transform). It reverts to the Skew transform which is not what I want (see image).

I can do this in certain documents but not others. I should mention that I’m trying to transform a linked AI file in PS. However, I’ve done the same thing with a linked PSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this out by copy/pasting an AI object into a PSD. I can confirm that many of the `Transform` operations are disabled as you said.

To remedy this, I right clicked on the `Vector Smart Object` layer and chose `Convert to Smart Object`. Now I have a Smart Object of a Smart Object and all of the `Transform` operations are enabled.

So if you want to edit the original vector in AI, then double-click the layer, and it'll open a .psb, then double click the layer there and it'll open an .ai

Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I just answered my own question, but can anyone confirm this? That only with a linked or embedded smart object PSD (not AI) can I Perspective Transform the document? It appears that I only see this with AI linked or embedded.

Figured if anyone else has this problem, that at least we'd have a question complete with an answer.